# Variance of a Weighted Sum of Data Points

Tags: variance, weighted-mean

I've been wracking my brain over something that seems very simple. I am working with a variable $Y$ that is a weighted sum of a series of data points. Each data point $X_i$ comes from the same distribution. That is, $Y$ is not a sum of different random variables.

$$Y = \sum_{i=1}^N w_i x_i$$

The weights are normalized, so $\sum_{i=1}^N w_i = 1$. I need to compute the variance of $Y$.

It's possible that an assumption that $X_i \sim N(0, \sigma_x^2)$ is being made.

I am working with some code that defines

$$\mbox{var }{Y} = \sum_{i=1}^N w_i^2 x_i^2$$

For the life of me I cannot figure out why this is correct. I can understand where $w_i^2$ comes from since $\mbox{var } aX = a^2 \mbox{var } X$. I have not been able to reproduce this using simulated data.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Your equation for the variance of $Y$ is only true if each $X_i$ are mutually independent. Otherwise, the expression for the variance of $Y$ would need to include cross-covariance terms for each $X_i$ and $X_j$. See [here](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter5/5_3_1_covariance_correlation.php) for details.

Comment: @mhdadk Right. That's another thing I am confused by.